# We'll put on a fresh pot and just talk about anything. (What does this sentence mean?)

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, idioms

> We'll put on a fresh pot and just talk about anything.

What does this phrase, 'put on a fresh pot', mean?

Comment: Please remember the **source** of the quote, Brandon.

Comment: Dude, really. You have 2000+ reputation and all you have is a single sentence?

Comment: Thx for advices. My intention was to get intuitively what you guys feel and think of at first sight of this sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not explict, but pot probably refers to "pot of tea", and "put on a fresh pot" is to make a new pot of tea to share.

Tea, in Britain in particular, is a popular drink to have while having a chat.

Answer (score 3):

To "put on a fresh pot" means to start making a fresh pot of coffee or tea.

In this context, the coffee or tea is to be enjoyed while talking about anything.